# Как найти элементы с одинаковым TagProperty? Возможно ли это?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть 2 элемента с одинаковым `Tag`:

```
<Menu Tag="Fixed"></Menu>

<Grid Tag="Fixed"></Grid>
```

В *Code-Behind* я хочу найти эти 2 элемента. Как это сделать?

---

Если нельзя найти элементы по `TagProperty`, то как можно найти несколько элементов с "чем-то" одинаковым (например: `Name`)?

Comment: Вы не должны совершенно не как хотеть работать в WPF с контролами из кода, используйте привязки, отделите данные от представления, ибо дальше вы сами себе будете подобным палки в колеса ставить. Ну если так хочется, то примерно так `var result = SomeElement.Children.OfType<Control>().Where(x => x.Tag == "Fixed");`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ прочитал бы я это полгода назад, понял бы только начиная с фразы "Ну если так хочется...". Да, это правда, когда в WPF начинаешь использовать MVVM (через боль и страдания по-началу), то открывается куча новых возможностей, и некоторые, с первого взгляда сложнейшие штуки, становится сделать легко, используя чуть ли не нативные методы. Но сам процесс обучения тяжелый, на мой взгляд. А кому-то не серьезные проекты писать хочется, а решить лабу или просто поиграться. Обучение шаблону MVVM здесь не всегда оправдано. Но я рекомендую автору пересилить себя и разобраться, оно того стоит. :)

Comment: @aepot Тут дело в желание. Если человеку хоть каплю захочется разобраться, то он это сделает, если же нет - увы, его не заставить. Писать подробную инструкцию как все это делать лично мне уже надоело, ибо не раз писал подробнейший гайд как и что, а следующим вопросом они на старые грабли наступают и я получается трачу несколько часов для написания в пустоту. Для этого лично я подобными "намекающими" комментариями "намекаю", что человек делает не правильно и если он захочет - я готов дать ответ, но только если будет у него желание в этом разобраться!

Comment: @aepot, вам бы тоже повнимательнее быть (то же, что и EvgeniyZ)! (с уважением)

Comment: @zodiak1 Понимаете в чем суть... Если идет разработка нормального приложения, то вы обязаны забыть про `имяКонтрола.Свойство = ...`, ибо это WPF, ключевой особенностью которого является привязки, стили. Если вам надо установить свойство всем контролам, то у вас должен быть класс, который содержит например `bool IsFixed` свойство, в стилях вы пишете `SomeProperty = "{Binding IsFixed}"` и все, вы больше не трогаете совершенно не как View слой, вот это тогда будет нормальное, WPF приложение. Сейчас же вы делаете кашу, где я уверен, в 1 классе у вас работа с данными и рядом `Контрол.Свойство = ..`

Comment: Так что вы сейчас идете совершенно не в том направление и тут уж простите, моя цель вас предупредить об этом, а слушать или нет - дело ваше.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, так как я таким образом при прокрутке смогу эти самые 2 контрола заставить двигаться вместе с прокруткой, создавая эффект фиксации этих контролов?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, мне все равно нужно лезть в код view и там прописывать обработчик скрола и искать эти самые элементы, изменять в них их margin. Может есть другой более MVVM способ?

Comment: @zodiak1 Я не знаю вашей задачи полностью, я без понятия о каком эффекте фиксации вы говорите, по этому сказать конкретное решение данной задачи не могу. Скорей всего вам надо переписать стиль контрола, где при помощи триггера он установит нужные значения объекту.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, хотя бы уже без Binding) Спасибо за ваши старания!

Comment: Чтобы слелать контрол "не прокручиваемым", его достаточно вынести за пределы прокручиваемого содержимого. WPF позволяет сколько угодно слоев контролов накладывать друг на друга. WPF - это не браузер, у WPF намного больше возможностей. И да, нейминг контролов в WPF - это легаси от WinForms, и при здоровой разработке классического MVVM приложения он не нужен, совсем.

Comment: @aepot, я понимаю, что можно вынести его из прокручиваемой области, но последнее, что я сделаю. Поэтому и пробую найти другие методы

Comment: Вы скорее всего не сможете оперативно реагировать на скролл. Я пробовал в винформсах давно, кнопка скачет, и это не лечится. Но попробуйте, может WPF как-то по-другому скролит.

Comment: Но мне не понятно, зачем прокручивать то, что не должно прокручиваться, и при этом втыкать костыль на непрокручивание, когда можно решить вопрос разметкой вообще без костылей.

Comment: @aepot, банальное желание сократить количество повторяющегося кода) В каждой view есть, то что скролиться и то, что по идее должно оставаться не прокручиваемым. Можно было просто все оставить как есть и в каждый view прописывать кнопку вверх и вытекающие необходимости. Но я подумал, что это не "круто"  и решил вынести эту кнопку в `MainWindow` и все view'шки отображать в `ScrollViewer`. Тогда не нужно в каждую view вставлять эту кнопку для прокрутки, но нужно "зафиксировать" те блоки, которые должны быть всегда видны не зависимо от скрола. Может из этого вы не сильно меня поймете) но все же

Comment: Понимаю. Но один `Grid` можно наложить на другой `Grid`, размеры их сеток можно синхронизировать с помощью `SharedSizeGroup` (если требуется), все это делается в xaml без лишнего кода. То есть можно в верстке `MainWindow` сделать непрокручиваемый контрол поверх прокручиваемого содержимого.